# Pygame.transform.rotate error

Tags: python, pygame

I am attempting to scale a surface in pygame but I am getting this error:

```
pygame.transform.scale(sprite.getSurface(), math.radians(sprite.getFaceAngle()))
TypeError: must be 2-item sequence, not float
```

My code is as follows:

```
pygame.transform.scale(sprite.getSurface(), math.radians(sprite.getFaceAngle()))
```

Comment: This can be safely closed/deleted

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory. http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale says the second argument should be (width, height). math.radians() only returns a float.

Comment: Ooops, meant to be rotate. Wouldnt have seen it if you wouldnt have posted though ;p